# getting Uncaught ReferenceError: using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following error while click on edit button using php.

> Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: edt_id is not defined
```

I am explaining my code below.

> index.php:

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CRUD Operations With PHP and MySql - By Cleartuts</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<center>

<div id="body">
 <div id="content">
    <table align="center">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="5"><a href="add_data.html">add data here.</a></th>
    </tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>City Name</th>
    <th colspan="2">Operations</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
 $sql_query="SELECT * FROM users";
 $result_set=mysql_query($sql_query);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result_set))
 {
  ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
  <td align="center"><a href="javascript:edt_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')"><img src="images/pencil_small.png" align="EDIT" /></a></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="javascript:delete_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')"><img src="images/cross-small-icon.png" align="DELETE" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
 }
 ?>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me resole this error.Here when user will click on edit button the user will redirect to `edit_data.php` page with `edt_id` with URL. Please help me.

Comment: So - what is `edt_id`, `delete_id`?

Comment: Maybe you mean something like `<a href="edit_data.php?edt_id=<?php echo urlencode($row[0]) ?>">`?

Comment: Do you **have** a javascript method named `edt_id`?

Comment: No,Sorry i dont have any method like that.

Comment: @AndreaGhidini:Can you answer for delete option ?

Comment: @satya it's similar to the edit option, change as needed the parameter and/or the page (I wrote an answer below guessing from your code)

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code:

- the error you are getting is a **javascript** one, not a PHP one (in fact you are reading the error in your browser development console)
- the links in your code executes a javascript method, hence the syntax `javascript:methodname()`

If you wish to simply create a link to another PHP file you can use plain HTML links without javascript code:

```
<td align="center"><a href="edit_data.php?edt_id=<?php echo urlencode($row[0]) ?>"><img src="images/pencil_small.png" align="EDIT" /></a></td>
<td align="center"><a href="edit_data.php?delete_id=<?php echo urlencode($row[0]) ?>"><img src="images/cross-small-icon.png" align="DELETE" /></a></td>
```

Change the path as needed in the `href` attributes, without knowing your app I can only guess. The PHP call `urlencode()` is needed to escape the data and avoid injection ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)).

Comment: :Dont need to redirect to any page for delete option.It should perform in same page with one alert prompt.

Comment: @satya To delete an item from your DB you need a server call, it can be an ajax one though.